# Rare behavior with mongodb cursor (DBCursor) in java, even though last element is already reached

Tags: java, mongodb, database-cursor

I have a collection called MyCollection that contains 200 elements in the bd MyDB in mongodb

```
> use MyDB
switched to db MyDB 
> db.MyCollection.count()
200
```

I'm getting a really rare behavior, even in the different ways I have used to load the cursor and iterate on it, this is my code:

```
DBCollection collection = getCollection("MyBD", "MyCollection");
DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
//DBCursor cursor = collection.find().limit(200); 
System.out.println("Cursor length: "+cursor.length());
Iterator<DBObject> itrc = cursor.iterator();
//while(cursor.hasNext()){
while (itrc.hasNext()) {
    //DBObject obj = (DBObject)cursor.next();
    DBObject obj = (DBObject)itrc.next();
    //BSONObject obj2 = (BSONObject)obj.get("scores");
    Integer intg = (Integer) obj.get("_id");
    System.out.println("_id:"+intg.toString());

    // operations remove and insert  on the collection
    // that affect the cursor behavior
    BasicDBList bl = (BasicDBList) obj.get("fieldArray");
    BasicDBObject bdo = new BasicDBObject();
    bdo.put("fieldArray", bl);
    Integer intid = (Integer) obj.get("_id");
    bdo.put("_id", intid);
    String str = (String) obj.get("fieldString");
    bdo.put("fieldString", str);
    collection.remove(obj);
    obj=null;
    collection.insert(bdo);

    if(intg.intValue()==199){
        System.out.println("Reached: "+intg.intValue());
    }   
}
```

This is the output:

```
Cursor length: 200
_id:0 _id:1 _id:2 _id:3 _id:4 _id:5 _id:6 _id:7 _id:8 _id:9 _id:10 _id:11 _id:12 _id:13 _id:14 _id:15 _id:16 _id:17 _id:18 _id:19 _id:20 _id:21 _id:22 _id:23 _id:24 _id:25 _id:26 _id:27 _id:28 _id:29 _id:30 _id:31 _id:32 _id:33 _id:34 _id:35 _id:36 _id:37 _id:38 _id:39 _id:40 _id:41 _id:42 _id:43 _id:44 _id:45 _id:46 _id:47 _id:48 _id:49 _id:50 _id:51 _id:52 _id:53 _id:54 _id:55 _id:56 _id:57 _id:58 _id:59 _id:60 _id:61 _id:62 _id:63 _id:64 _id:65 _id:66 _id:67 _id:68 _id:69 _id:113 _id:101 _id:102 _id:103 _id:104 _id:105 _id:106 _id:107 _id:108 _id:109 _id:110 _id:111 _id:112 _id:114 _id:115 _id:116 _id:117 _id:118 _id:119 _id:120 _id:121 _id:122 _id:123 _id:124 _id:125 _id:126 _id:127 _id:128 _id:129 _id:130 _id:131 _id:132 _id:133 _id:134 _id:135 _id:136 _id:137 _id:138 _id:139 _id:140 _id:141 _id:142 _id:143 _id:144 _id:145 _id:146 _id:147 _id:148 _id:149 _id:150 _id:151 _id:152 _id:153 _id:154 _id:155 _id:156 _id:157 _id:158 _id:159 _id:160 _id:161 _id:162 _id:163 _id:164 _id:165 _id:166 _id:167 _id:168 _id:169 _id:170 _id:171 _id:172 _id:173 _id:174 _id:175 _id:176 _id:177 _id:178 _id:179 _id:180 _id:181 _id:182 _id:183 _id:184 _id:185 _id:186 _id:187 _id:188 _id:189 _id:190 _id:191 _id:192 _id:193 _id:194 _id:195 _id:196 _id:197 _id:198 _id:199
***************************
Reached: 199
***************************
 _id:70 _id:71 _id:72 _id:73 _id:74 _id:75 _id:76 _id:77 _id:78 _id:79 _id:80 _id:81 _id:82 _id:83 _id:84 _id:85 _id:86 _id:87 _id:88 _id:89 _id:90 _id:91 _id:92 _id:93 _id:94 _id:95 _id:96 _id:97 _id:98 _id:99 _id:100_id:96 _id:97 _id:98 _id:99 _id:100
```

As it can see , once the limit of 200 elements is reached (element _id:199), it jumps to  the element with _id:70, then it repeats 31 additional iterations until the element _id:100 is reached, instead than finished in the right time that would be at the 200 iteration.

The alternatives: the one is commented in the code (using the cursor's method: hasNext()) and the other one that is running (using an Iterator) both have the same output.

If I remove the operations part  on the collection (remove/insert in my case), then the rare behavior does not happen.

This is the expected output:

```
Cursor length: 200
_id:0 _id:1 _id:2 _id:3 _id:4 _id:5 _id:6 _id:7 _id:8 _id:9 _id:10 _id:11 _id:12 _id:13 _id:14 _id:15 _id:16 _id:17 _id:18 _id:19 _id:20 _id:21 _id:22 _id:23 _id:24 _id:25 _id:26 _id:27 _id:28 _id:29 _id:30 _id:31 _id:32 _id:33 _id:34 _id:35 _id:36 _id:37 _id:38 _id:39 _id:40 _id:41 _id:42 _id:43 _id:44 _id:45 _id:46 _id:47 _id:48 _id:49 _id:50 _id:51 _id:52 _id:53 _id:54 _id:55 _id:56 _id:57 _id:58 _id:59 _id:60 _id:61 _id:62 _id:63 _id:64 _id:65 _id:66 _id:67 _id:68 _id:69 _id:113 _id:101 _id:102 _id:103 _id:104 _id:105 _id:106 _id:107 _id:108 _id:109 _id:110 _id:111 _id:112 _id:114 _id:115 _id:116 _id:117 _id:118 _id:119 _id:120 _id:121 _id:122 _id:123 _id:124 _id:125 _id:126 _id:127 _id:128 _id:129 _id:130 _id:131 _id:132 _id:133 _id:134 _id:135 _id:136 _id:137 _id:138 _id:139 _id:140 _id:141 _id:142 _id:143 _id:144 _id:145 _id:146 _id:147 _id:148 _id:149 _id:150 _id:151 _id:152 _id:153 _id:154 _id:155 _id:156 _id:157 _id:158 _id:159 _id:160 _id:161 _id:162 _id:163 _id:164 _id:165 _id:166 _id:167 _id:168 _id:169 _id:170 _id:171 _id:172 _id:173 _id:174 _id:175 _id:176 _id:177 _id:178 _id:179 _id:180 _id:181 _id:182 _id:183 _id:184 _id:185 _id:186 _id:187 _id:188 _id:189 _id:190 _id:191 _id:192 _id:193 _id:194 _id:195 _id:196 _id:197 _id:198 _id:199
***************************
Reached: 199
***************************
```

I had found a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12145579/833336), but it is not clear to me:

- how can the operations remove/insert affect the cursor behavior in the way I have exposed before?
- how  can I use the snapshot option?
- thinking ahead, what about if I need to work with the ordered collection?

BTW, if I use the option without iterator, like this:

```
while(cursor.hasNext()){
    DBObject obj = (DBObject)cursor.next();
```

- Why do I have to delete the next line?

  System.out.println("Cursor length: "+cursor.length());

In order to avoid the next exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't switch cursor access methods
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._checkType(DBCursor.java:412)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:483)
    at tasks.UpdateRemoveHW.main(Test.java:56)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just throw the Exception IllegalArgumentException, then you get that use of DBCursor.length()  will already converted curser into an array.So after that using hasnext(), next is illegegal. If you want to use hasnext() or next() better to remove length() before iteration.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is happening with your rare behaviour in the first part of your question, however in general it is unsafe to modify any data structure while you are iterating over it except via the Iterator.remove() method.

---

The last part of your question is indirectly answered by the following **Warning** at the top of the [API Documentation for DBCursor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html):

> **Warning**: Calling toArray or length on a DBCursor will irrevocably turn it into an array. This means that, if the cursor was iterating over ten million results (which it was lazily fetching from the database), suddenly there will be a ten-million element array in memory. Before converting to an array, make sure that there are a reasonable number of results using skip() and limit().

If you read the [source code for DBCursor (line 483)](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/com/mongodb/DBCursor.java#L483) where it is throwing the **IllegalArgumentException** you can see that any call to DBCursor.length() turns the cursor into an array, after which time all calls to DBCursor.next() or DBCursor.hasNext() become Illegal.

I think this behaviour definately violates the [Principle of Least Surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).  Arrays can still have Iterators, so it would be better if the internal data structure was hidden and the Iterator methods continue to work.  Also, calling DBCursor.length() does not have to fetch any the records from the DB, I think it should behave similar to DBCursor.count() but somehow take into account limit() and skip() and then cache the result.