# Mongodb cursor inconsistent behavior

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a collection with over a billion documents. When I iterate over them with the cursor and do some processing, I don't get all the docs. However, if I just iterate over the collection and count, it does return the right count.

```
double c = 0;
while(cursor.hasNext){
      DBObject entity = entities.next();
      //do something
      c+=1
    }
 assert(c==446642690.0)
```

The assertion fails unless I don't do anything and simply count.

Comment: your question remember to me mine  http://stackoverflow.com/q/15461138/833336

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing updates or deletes during your processing? If that is the case you are running into the issue that a mongo cursor is not isolated from updates/inserts during its lifetime. You can partially avoid that behaviour with the [snapshot mode](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/snapshot/) but it's really limited. See the [mongo documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#cursor-behaviors) under cursor isolation for more information about this issue. As mongo is designed to work this way I think you need to find a way to deal with the situation.